# How to get detail information of ReferenceError in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

ReferenceError happen when we use undefined variable, this can happen very easy. In this case in my terminal appear something like:

> ReferenceError: usrname is not defined

Is there any way to get detail information of this, such as file and linenumber where it happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You get stack trace when you have referenceError in nodejs.

```
ReferenceError: d is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\test.js:5:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:467:10)
    at startup (node.js:134:18)
    at node.js:961:3
```

The above stack trace clearly mentions `test.js:5:13` which are filename, line no and column no respectively.

Comment: @John Please mark this as answer if it helped you in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can catch the `ReferenceError` being thrown, then you can inspect its `stack` property, which will have file, line and column information:

```
try {
  // suspect code
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.stack);
}
```

You can also try handling `uncaughtException`:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (e) {
  console.log(e.stack);
  process.exit(1);
});
```